# Make windows 7 search (windows-key) perform simple calculations, like spotlight?

Tags: windows, search, spotlight

Is it possible to have Windows 7 perform simple calculations in the "Search programs and files" text box that pops op when you press the 'start button' (or press the windows logo key)? Perhaps using some sort of plugin?

I am looking for similar behavior like [spotlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotlight_%28software%29) (Mac), [launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) (Windows) or [quicksilver](http://docs.blacktree.com/quicksilver/what_is_quicksilver) where you can type e.g. 5+3 and it will give you 8.

Answer (score 2):

You could just download [Command Line Calculator](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Home-Education/Command-line-Calculator.shtml) into your path (e.g. c:\windows) and then just type "clc 5+3" in the run menu.

Comment: A shame the Windows build-in calc.exe utility doesn't support this operation in Windows'Run menu.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. You will have to look for a separate program to do this. Why not just use Launchy?

Comment: If available, any build-in solution is to be preferred over extra programs or utilities. I was a huge fan of all these little utilities but I've come from that: they require updating, might become incompatible with the next OS upgrade, are not available on someone else's computer and need to be installed after every reinstall of an operating system.

Comment: Fair enough. I agree with you, but unfortunately you cannot do this without resorting to third-party applications.

Answer (score 0):

I also searched for this a while ago. There is a solution, which works fine and has exactly what you want:

http://robotification.com/start-menu-calculator/

Comment: Hmm, looks good. Although it does require an extra tool to install

Answer (score 0):

We're 8 years later and I've settled on the following build-in approach:

- Pin the build-in Calculator to the taskbar (open it >  right-click in taskbar > Pin this program to taskbar)
- Drag it to a position in the taskbar you choose, e.g. the 4th one.
- Easily open the calculator using the shortcut <kbd>win</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd> (if the icon is in the 4th position on the taskbar)

(I've pinned other programs that I use a lot in other, to fixed places in my taskbar, and I use the <kbd>win</kbd>-<kbd>position</kbd>)